# c++ program to raise a number to power gives error (expected unqualified id before 'for')

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

for loop isn't working in this cpp program

I tried changing for conditions but that doesn't work either.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int num(int num1, int num2) {
    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
        result = result * num2;
        return result;
    }
}
int main() {
    cout << num(2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've edited your question to remove the typo, but now your code compiles just fine. You're not returning on all paths, but that's not the error message you're describing.

Comment: The down votes are not because you are new. They are because the code you have posted does not have the error in the title. Please make sure that you post the correct code for the problem you are describing.

Comment: You are not using the `num1` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

please move `return` to out of loop .like:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < num2 ; i++){
        result  = result * num2;
        
}
return result ;
```